# Sorting methods in OpenAPI / Swagger by name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger

I want to make and order of the API Methods on Swagger index and keep them grouped according to Get, Post, Put and Delete. The methods are ordered on my page as mentioned on [How to sort methods by path?](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/issues/11). As the workaround on that page are too old, I am looking for a solution that can be used for the latest methods. Is it possible to make an order for the API methodsin ASP.NET Core app by making a config changes on Startup.cs, etc?

Comment: How do you generate your swagger docs? There are multiple ways that these can be generated and the answer will depend on which one you're curently using.

Comment: I use NSwag Studio. Can I also use Swashbuckle.AspNetCore as mentioned below?

Answer (score 7):

Firstly,Install package `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`:

```
Install-Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore -Version 5.5.0
```

Then you could configure like below:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.OrderActionsBy((apiDesc) => $"{apiDesc.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["controller"]}_{apiDesc.RelativePath}");
    //...
});
```

Result:
[image]

**Update:**

If you do not contains controller,just using:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.OrderActionsBy((apiDesc) => $"{apiDesc.RelativePath}");  //change here...
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseSwagger();
      
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API Test Version 1");
    });
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had tried to use this approach from GitHub. When using it, I encounter "*IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddSwaggerGen' and no accessible extension method 'AddSwaggerGen' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*" error when using `AddSwaggerGen`.

Comment: Similarly when trying to use with `AddSwagger`, this time I encounter "*'AspNetCoreOpenApiDocumentGeneratorSettings' does not contain a definition for 'OrderActionsBy' and no accessible extension method 'OrderActionsBy' accepting a first argument of type 'AspNetCoreOpenApiDocumentGeneratorSettings' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*" error. It may be due to version problem. Or maybe I apply something missing. Any idea?

Comment: Be sure add package `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`.You said you want a latest method,so I  use asp.net core 3.1 with the newest `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`.

Comment: Thanks, voted up. What about using NSwag Studio? Can I also use `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`?

Comment: Yes, but it has not solved the problem yet. So, after installing `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` I encounter *"'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddSwaggerGen' and the best extension method overload 'SwaggerGenServiceCollectionExtensions.AddSwaggerGen(IServiceCollection, Action<SwaggerGenOptions>)' requires a receiver of type 'IServiceCollection'"* error.

Comment: regarding to the page, I also tried to use that approach, but I  do not use Controller and Action names in my route and I need to sort the API methods without using these parameters as `[HttpGet("{id}")]`. Any idea?

Comment: Be sure the service is added in `ConfigureServices` not `Configure` method in Startup.cs.Check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, it is important I know and the place that I use is correct. On the other hand, I re-tried your update, but unfortunately it did not make any sense. May it be related to my API method notations? I use the following methods with given notations. Both method names are `Get` and I use `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpGet("{id}")]`. Is there any problem regarding to the definitions?

Comment: It actually work well in my project with httpverb attribute.I suggest that you could create a new simple project which could reproduce the issue and share with us.

Comment: Could you give me a sample Startup.cs by adding all the related path of Swagger and its config? As far as I see, there is no problem on API method annotations. On the other hand, I also use `[ApiController]` and `[Route("api/[controller]")]` in the `ApiController` and I think it is the same as yours.

Comment: Actually what I updated before is my whole Startup.cs.`I also use [ApiController] and [Route("api/[controller]")] in the ApiController and I think it is the same as yours.`  Yes,It is the same as mine...